# Access point internet connection through ethernet wall port?

Tags: ethernet, internet-connection, wireless-access-point

Does access point need to be connected directly to the router or would it also work if I connect it to an ethernet port in the wall?

The reason I'm asking is because the router is downstairs in the house I live in, but the wifi connection is very poor in my upstairs room. I have an ethernet wall port in my room and I can connect to internet via ethernet cable, but I want to connect wirelessly. I was going to get an access point but all the articles I've read mentions that it needs to be connected to the router.

I wanted to ask whether I can use access point if I connect it to the ethernet wall port instead of connecting it to the router.

Comment: If the other end of that in-wall Ethernet cable connects to a LAN port on your router (even if it's by way of a patch panel and an Ethernet switch), then you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

The physical connection doesn't matter at all. The access point isn't using some special kind of electrical signalling – it's just exchanging Ethernet data packets like a computer or any other device would. So as long as it's in the same logical Ethernet network, it can't tell the difference between a direct connection and being connected through 5 switches and a powerline adapter.